# <defaultDocument> in web.config adding last lash to URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web

I have the strangest error. I am uploading my .NET 4.0 application on a new server and want to set the default document in the web.config file using the code below.

```
 <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="http://domain/folder/home.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  <system.webServer>
```

The problem is when the page is loaded it goes to http://domain/folder/home.aspx/ with a last lash added which causes the header and menu not to load. If I delete the last lash after the URL everything loads fine.

My question is how to I set the default page without the last lash adding to the URL.

I tried setting the default document from the control panel on my server but it will not allow me to route to a sub folder

Comment: Have you tried to set it in IIS?

Comment: It is not allowing me to add a subfolder

Comment: You'll have to go into more detail by updating your question. Perhaps include screenshots of what you're attempting in IIS.